# How do I add the value of the for loop to a <LI> and style it?

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = ['hi' , 'hi there' , 'hi there again' , 'sup'];

var myList  = document.getElementById('list');    // i have an li with an id of list

      function hello(){
         for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
           document.write(myArray[i] + '<br/>')

         }

      };

   hello();
```

I'm new to javascript :)

Comment: you need to edit your question, where do you want to add it, to what element?

Comment: You need to look to dom manipulation in Javascript.

Comment: <ul>
    <li id="list"></li>
  </ul>
i want to add it to this li

Comment: So, you want to insert the `id` of the element in the array in the list element? Like so `<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,try this :

```
var myArray = ['hi' , 'hi there' , 'hi there again' , 'sup'];

var myList  = document.getElementById('list').parentNode;    
function hello(){
   for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
       myList.innerHTML+='<li class="list">'+myArray[i]+'</li>';
}

hello();
```

This will generate this :

```
<ul>
  <li id='list'></li>  <!-- As mentioned in the question -->
  <li class='list'>hi</li>
  <li class='list'>hi there</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Read more about [.parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) and [.innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

Comment: You cannot have more than one ID of the same name on the page. This would not validate and is incorrect HTML.

Comment: You are right. But since he wanted it...I never checked it out.Anyway, I'll just change it to class.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `document.write()` because that only works when the page is loading, and is considered bad practice. You should instead use `+=` on the `.innerHTML` property of a list.

The `a += b` operator is short form for `a = a+b`;

It appends `b` to the current value of `a`, and you are running it in a loop so it adds on each time.

### HTML

```
<ul id='content'></ul>
```

### Javascript

```
var myArray = ['hi' , 'hi there' , 'hi there again' , 'sup'];
var content = document.getElementById('content');
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    ul.innerHTML += ('<li>'+myArray[i] + '</li>')
}
```

Demo of code : http://jsfiddle.net/m60ur50z/2/

Comment: This would be an incorrect usage of HTML. You can only put <li> tags inside of a <ul> http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to set the `innerHTML` property of your list to be a string of 'li' tags with content written in, like so:

```html
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  html += '<li>' + myArray[i] + '</li>'
}
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = html;
```

For what it's worth, doing DOM manipulation tasks like this is often done with a library, e.g. jQuery, simply because it makes selecting and adding to the HTML document so much easier. But if you want to do it in vanilla JS, the above works. Using the DOM API with its "appendChild" methods and such is painful and generally to be avoided.

Comment: Read the question properly and the comments on the question.

Comment: Best answer +1, minimal code, and reference to javascript frameworks.

Comment: The Id of the 'li' has to be 'list' and not of the 'ul' tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure DOM methods

```
var myArray = ['hi', 'hi there', 'hi there again', 'sup'];

var myList = document.getElementById('list'); // i have an li with an id of list

function hello() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[i]));
        myList.appendChild(listItem);
    }
};
hello();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgautsch/43yf7sb4/